# In Mortal Engines, why do Londoners cheer when M.E.D.U.S.A destroys the wall?

Tags: mortal-engines

In *Mortal Engines*, why do Londoners cheer when M.E.D.U.S.A. destroys the wall? Don't they feel the horror of killing so many people?

Comment: Kill or be killed is the lesson here.

Comment: Are you asking about the book or the film?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - In the book, the Medusa weapon exploded and the shield-wall was left intact.

Comment: "*“London’s not a barbarian city!” shouted Tom. “It’s you who are the barbarians! Why shouldn’t London eat Batmunkh Gompa if it needs to? If you don’t like the idea, you should have put your cities on wheels long ago, like civilized people!”*"

Comment: You are talking about a population who cheer whenever a smaller city engine is captured and devoured...?  Its a sport, its entertainment.  The crowd has been conditioned to love it.  Why does boxing and cage fighting attract huge crowds?  For the same reason.